# How can I "undo" fetchmail/copy the mails back to my IMAP server?

Tags: imap, fetchmail

Well... as already stated I did a pretty dumb move by using fetchmail without the "keep" option, and now my mails are, of course, all offline. What's the best way to put them all back on the IMAP server?

Comment: For some reason the OP's own answer was deleted, but seems relevant to me: _"After some more searching, I found this neat Python script which has been made for exactly this task: http://imap-upload.sourceforge.net/ "_

Answer (score 0):

Easiest might be to clicky and draggy the emails in some GUI client from the local folder back up to the server, or equivalent operations in e.g. `mutt` with IMAP support, or a program:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138604/perl-imap-move-message-to-trash-mailimapclient